# Show $z^5+6z^3-10$ has exactly two zeroes on the annulus $2<\vert z \vert<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

So I need to show and find the zeros of

$$z^5+6z^3-10$$

on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 2 < \vert z \vert < 3\}$.

Whats the quickest way of doing this? I was reading Gamelin-Greene and they split the function into BIG+little. Here is $6z^3$ my big and $z^5-10$ my little? OR By Rouche's Theorem can I let $f(z)=z^5+6z^3-10$ and let $h(z)=z^5-10$?

Comment: On the reals, the function is strictly increasing, so there is only one real root, between $1$ and $2.$ The other roots come in complex number pairs, so there are either $0,$ $2$ or $4$ in the annulus. There can't be four, because the product of the roots is $-10.$ So there are $0$ or $2.$

Comment: Use Rouches theorem to show that there are 3 zeros $|z|<2$, then again use it to show there are 5 zeros $|z|<3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to study the number of solutions of $z^5+6z^3-10=0$ on $\mathbb D_3(0)\setminus\mathbb D_2(0)$. For both regions we can find an open set $\Omega$ such that $ \mathbb D_2(0),\mathbb D_3(0)\subset \Omega$.

For $\mathbb D_3(0):$ let $f(z)=z^5$ and $g(z)=6z^3-10$, with $f,g\in H(\Omega)$. Then, for $z\in\partial \mathbb D_3(0)$,
$$|6z^3-10|\le6|z|^3-10=6\cdot 3^3-10<3^5=|z|^5;$$
($f,g\in H(\Omega)$ + $|f\vert_{\partial D}|>|g\vert_{\partial D}|$ $\implies N_0(f+g,D)=N_0(f,D)$)

For $\mathbb D_2(0):$ let $f(z)=6z^3$ and $g(z)=z^5-10$. Then, for $z\in\partial \mathbb D_2(0)$, we have
$$|z^5-10|\le |z|^5-10=22<6\cdot 2^3=6|z|^3;$$
For Rouche theorem $N_0(z^5+6z^3-10,\mathbb D_3(0)\setminus\mathbb D_2(0))=5-3=2.$

Comment: By $\mathbb{D}_n(0)$ you're referring to the radius $n$ disk about the origin correct? And To find the number of zeroes between 3 and 2 you subtract the number of zeroes at 3 to the number of zeroes at the radius 2? @Vajra

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Exactly